# How can I get a GridPanel to show the correct time in ExtJS 4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, gridpanel

I have a `GridPanel` with ExtJS 4.  One of the columns returns a timestamp in the following format:

```
1900-01-01 14:00:00.0
```

This is my column from my JsonStore

```
{
    name: 'clockOut',
    mapping: 'clockOut',
    dateFormat: 'H:i A',
    type: 'date'
}
```

I just want to show the `time` section but all I get back is a blank column.
When I remove the `type: 'data'` I get the data but in the above format.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a renderer to the column that formats it the way you want:

```
{
 name: 'clockOut',
 mapping: 'clockOut',
 renderer: dateRenderer
}
```

And then a function for `dateRenderer`:

```
function dateRenderer(value, id, r) {
 var d = new Date(r.data['clockOut']);
 return d.format('H:i A');
}
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting a renderer but it still doesn't work.  Look at my modification here:  https://gist.github.com/981266

Comment: Just confirmed the `renderer` does nothing.  I removed it and left the `type:'date'` in and it rendered the long text (`Mon Jan 01 2010....`)

Comment: I'm an idiot.  I hadn't changed the column type to a `datecolumn` so the custom renderer wasn't needed.

Comment: Sweet, glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You could even use ExtJS built in renderer instead of defining your own function:

`renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('H:i A')`